# Springdoc Open-Api Restless Api Documentations

Tags: spring, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

I am new in springdoc open-api. I am using spring microservices but instead of springs default mapping annotations, i use some other platform. Is there way to tell spring-doc to look for other annottaions instead of springs default mappings? or is there a way to tell spring-doc to show some non-endpoint methods in swagger-ui.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

As it is clearly stated in the [springdoc official website](https://springdoc.org/), `springdoc` relies on Spring Boot:

> springdoc-openapi java library helps to automate the generation of API
> documentation using spring boot projects.

This means that unless you are using Spring, you can't use `springdoc`. The best you can do is get it to work without using Spring Boot, but still using Spring Framework as described in https://springdoc.org/#how-to-integrate-open-api-3-with-spring-project-not-spring-boot.